# tomcat without apache is port 8009 necessary

Tags: security, tomcat, port

1) Tomcat running on a linux configuration
2) No apache server.
=> is port 8009 necessary or can it be closed for security purpose, without impairing tomcat?

Thank you.

Comment: It depends what you're using it for. Tomcat can use whatever port you want it to use over whatever protocol. If you're not using it on 8009, then it makes sense to either change it to something you will use or just get rid of it.

Comment: Thank you Mike. I use it for servlets and basic html pages on port 80 solely. does this mean that I can close all other ports than 80? Knowing I dont need mail,ssh, ftp and all the stuff? This is a first question. The second would be, how to start the cat if 8005 is closed, is there a work around?

Answer (score 0):

You can safely disable the AJP connector (default on 8009) without any changings in your Tomcat. But it won't do anything for security, cause you might have blocked all ports in the firewall for sure.

**Update**

No it only closes 8009. Simply enable "HTTP/1.1" on port 80 and comment out "AJP":

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>

<!--<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>-->
```

Comment: Thank you Stefan. Do you mean that closing 8009 would close all ports as a side effect? Including 80, which is the only one of interest to me. What I need is the cat running with only 80 opened. It this doable?